# html5 pattern for cc expiry mm/yy

Tags: regex, html, forms, input

I'm trying to figure out a pattern regex for credit card expiry date input that would return `mm/yy`

currently I came across `yyyy-mm-dd` pattern represented like this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))" />
```

That I tried to edit, but I can't seem to get it right for `mm/yy`

Comment: This regex match yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @Jimbot updated the question, original answer said it matched `dd/mm/yyyy` however

Comment: Just remove the `day` part and century and put it in right order: `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/\d\d`

Comment: Sorry, but it don't, just checked it: [https://regex101.com/r/c3qlyV/1](https://regex101.com/r/c3qlyV/1)

Comment: Well, if you just need to check for `01`-`12` months followed with any 2 digits, you may as well use `pattern="(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/\d{2}"`

Comment: Or are you after replacing `-` with `/` delimiter? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Stated in question, regex for `mm/yy` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex, it should work:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="([0-9]{2}[/]?){2}" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It matches two({2}) digits([0-9]) plus an hypothetical "/"([/]?), all this two times.

The first one it will match "mm/", then just the "yy" part.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you use this pattern, user couldn't enter invalid months number like "34" - first number has to be "0" or "1". "/" is not optional here.
Also "title" can help user to enter valid code sending additional message in tooltip.

```
<form>
  <input 
    type="text"
    pattern="(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{2}"
    title="Enter a date in this format MM/YY"
  />

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```